# building jboss fuse 7.2 from source

Tags: jbossfuse

I'm interested in building JBoss fuse 7.2 from source. I am unable to locate the source tree for this.  How is this product built? RedHat makes it very hard to build their products from source except CentOS.  I have tried the jboss-fuse/fuse on github, but that project seems rather dated and hasn't anything since 6.3 fuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fuse 7 is in https://github.com/jboss-fuse/fuse-karaf repository. It's public. Branch for 7.2 is https://github.com/jboss-fuse/fuse-karaf/tree/7.x.redhat-7-2-x.